# How to use traffic manager to failover a custom service endpoint?

Tags: azure

I want to provide a failover proof URL for my service endpoint to users using traffic management. I have a service instance running at http://vm1.cloudapp.net/myservice:8888/index.html. If this instance goes down then the service auto starts on vm2 at http://vm2.cloudapp.net/myservice:8888/index.html and vice versa.

I want Azure to hide the underlying service URLs to user and expose the service at http://myservice.trafficmanager.net

Is this possible? If so, how? From reading the documentation of traffic manager service, it looks like you can failover only at DNS level and not at URL endpoint level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setup traffic manager for both endpoints as failover and add a CNAME entry in your dns from www.yourdomain.com to myservice.trafficmanager.net.

Users will only see www.yourdomain.com no matter if they are connecting to vm1.cloudapp.net or vm2.cloudapp.net. Works the same way even if you use directly myservice.trafficmanager.net instead of a custom domain.